# "Service_References" namespace emerges for WCF references

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, service-reference

I have a project which references 5-7 of my own WCF services and I have encountered a very annoying problem.

When I update service references, sometimes they create additional namespace, but sometimes don't.

For example, I add reference to my `SomeWcfService` in my `MyMvcProject`.
It will automatically generate a namespace

```
MyMvcProject.SomeWcfService.SomeDataContract
```

After an hour of work, I need to update it. I click Update reference and Visual Studio creates an updated code...but in namespace

```
MyMvcProject.Service_Reference.SomeWcfService.SomeDataContract
```

You can imagine how annoying it is - all `using` statements break and I get 50+ compile errors which take a lot of time to be fixed. I have found a solution - update references again and again until it creates a necessary namespace, but it is not a solution.

Why does it happen? There should be a reason - it can't just be a random. And how to solve this?

Comment: Would you mind sending me a simple demo application that can reproduce the issue? My email address is [lali AT microsoft DOT com] (please replace AT with '@', and replace DOT with '.'). Besides, what's the version of your Visual Studio?  -- Lan

Comment: Hello, with VS2010 I have exactly the same problem as you Yeldar. Sometimes the proxy is generated with a namespace at the root of my assembly, sometimes it generates it inside of a "Service_References" sub namespace. Very annoying, like you said. Found no solution yet. Did you find something to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: @AFract As mentionted in answer, I stopped using service references, since I was going to do that in a long time. One tip: try selecting `Service References` directory, open Properties window and check if its `Namespace Provider` property is set to false. This might help, but I am not sure if it does. Also, there is a chance that this property is not a part of VS, but a part of Resharper.

Comment: I've never noticed this "Namespace provider" property before. I set it to false, it seems to generate the desired code so I'll work with it and see if the problem happens again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing it but a solution would be to drop all your service references and just call the services directly via the runtime generated proxy returned from `ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel();`

There is no reason I can think of to prefer the use of system generated service references over this method, especially as you say you own and control all the services anyway.

The code generation behind service references is complex and fickle and, while ultimately deterministic, is certainly unpredictable and adds another layer of stuff that can go wrong to your client application.